# How to get the downloaded zip file from iPhone app

Tags: iphone, file-sharing, nsdocumentdirectory

Iam developing one application.In that iam downloading the zip file and unzip that one.When i connect my iphone to PC,is there any chance to user to get that downloaded file or that Unzip file from PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, with software [IExplorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/) you can retrieve (almost) any file from the iOS device.

Comment: Then how can i save that downloaded data without user interaction.

Comment: We you say user interaction and mean with out the user get the data, you can't. You might just want encrypt the data. But as soon as you save it with out encryption on the file system the user can access it.

Comment: But every time when the app is open i need to use that unzip data.

Comment: unzip it in memory would be your only option if you wan't to be safe.

Comment: if i set UIFileSharingEnabled to NO then is there any chance to get the data?

Comment: Yes, with [IExplorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/) you can get to the files without any problem.

Comment: How can i avoid that one also?Is there any way?

Comment: I al ready explained that in my previous comment, you can't without encrypting the data on the file system.